# Google sheets script. Как скопировать активный(выделенный) диапазон

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Очень прошу помощи в нелегкой для меня задачи. Собственно цель какая: мне нужен пример скрипта хотяб, чтобы я выделил некий диапазон с помощью скрипта скопировал его и вставил на другой Лист этой же книги, но чтобы вставлял в ближайшую пустую строку. Я так понимаю нужен цикл, но я новичок и не знаю за что схватится..  помогите кто может. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже относительно новичок в GAS
Попробуйте такой, более-менее, простой для понимания способ, без использования цикла

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName('Лист1');
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2');

  var activeRange = sh0.getActiveRange();
  var valActR = activeRange.getValues();

  var lrSh1 = sh1.getLastRow();
  var nCols = activeRange.getNumColumns();
  var nRows = activeRange.getNumRows();

  sh1.getRange(lrSh1 + 1, 1, nRows, nCols).setValues(valActR);

}
```

На Лист1 у вас данные для копирования
Лист2 - куда вставляете данные
Делайте кнопку, установите на неё функцию, активируйте нужный диапазон для копирования, нажимайте, проверяйте

Comment: Спасибо, но ничего не происходит при выполнении скрипта(

Comment: А нет, есть, но добавляет в самый конец таблицы